# Connection time Dulles

Tags: layovers, short-connections, united-airlines, lufthansa, iad

We booked our flight through Expedia and are
traveling on 2 airlines, one PNR and no checked baggage.

Flight from Chicago on United arrives at 8:45 pm.  Flight to Lisbon on
Lufthansa leaves at 10:20.  Just checking if that sounds like enough time - not sure which terminals we arrive at/depart from. Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Are both these flights on a single PNR?

Comment: Are both flights on a single booking (one PNR)? Will you have checked-in bags to reclaim or are you travelling carry-on only? Does the booking confirmation give the gate details? Allowing for gate closure around 20-30 minutes  before departure, you effectively have about 1 hour to make the connection to your international flight, which on the face of it doesn’t allow much room for delays

Comment: Yes, one PNR and no checked bags.

Comment: I agree with Traveller: it's going to be close. OTOH, that the airline and Expedia allowed the bookings suggest that they think it's likely you'll make it, and that there are other flights daily Dulles > Lisbon means even if you miss the flight for which you're scheduled, it's likely the airline will get to your destination the same day as originally planned.